# Install another gcc version

Tags: fedora, gcc

I'm trying to compile NVIDIA CUDA on a Fedora 24 Workstation.

I'm using CUDA version 7.5 and when I try to compile it I get this method:

> gcc versions later than 4.9 are not supported!

I have installed:

> gcc (GCC) 6.1.1.20160621 (Red Hat 6.1.1-3).

How can I install gcc 4.9 on my machine?

My question is related to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622454/cuda-incompatible-with-my-gcc-version), but on that one doesn't tell how to install to different gcc versions on the same machine.

On ubuntu I can do it with this command:

> sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9 g++-4.9

But I have a Fedora 24.

Answer (score 1):

There are `compat-gcc*` packages providing older version of GCC on Fedora. You can find them in [koji](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/search?match=glob&type=package&terms=compat-gcc*) and install them using `dnf` (version 3.4):

```
dnf install compat-gcc-34
```

Comment: That's _much, much_ too old. CUDA 7 supports GCC 4.9.x

Answer (score 1):

Devtoolset-2 provides g++-4.8.2 : # `dnf install --nogpgcheck devtoolset-2-gcc-c++`

Further INFO : Please read my post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37774923/downgrading-c-c-compiler-on-fedora-23-to-a-matlab-r2016a-compatible-compiler/37776358#37776358

---

And devtoolset-3 provides g++-4.9.2 . No repo for Fedora 24, but with no extra dependencies for these EL7 packages, they install easily. ... The four packages :

```
devtoolset-3-gcc-4.9.2-6.2.el7.x86_64.rpm
devtoolset-3-gcc-c++-4.9.2-6.2.el7.x86_64.rpm
devtoolset-3-libstdc++-devel-4.9.2-6.2.el7.x86_64.rpm
devtoolset-3-runtime-3.1-12.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

... are available as one package, devtoolset-3-gcc-c++_el7.tar
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNeElrMmc0TTlYLWM/view?usp=sharing

Unpack, and

```
cd devtoolset-3-gcc-c++_el7/
# dnf install ./*
```

Be aware that the command `scl enable devtoolset-3 bash` enables gcc/g++ v4.9 in the current terminal session only.

---

EDIT : A copy of the CentOS7 repo files and the "key file" works perfect in Fedora 24. Just copy {CentOS-SCLo-scl-rh.repo, CentOS-SCLo-scl.repo} to /etc/yum.repos.d/, and RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-SIG-SCLo to /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/ .

Files, CentOS-SCLo-scl-el7.tar.gz https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNSnR0TkJKbm5qMDQ/view?usp=sharing

Install : # `dnf install devtoolset-3-gcc-c++`

Comment: I don't find devtoolset packages when I `dnf search devtoolset`. What repository/ies do I need?

Comment: RHEL 7 : `yum install centos-release-scl-rh` ... Easy to find. Type devtoolset-4 in Google https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-4/ ... or devtoolset-3 https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-3/